# How to edit data to 2 tables using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

How to edit data in 2 tables using MySQL Workbench (or can I)?
I use the below query to get the data but unable to edit it from the table (or Form Editor).

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    TABLE1
        INNER JOIN
    TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE
    TABLE1.ID = 1
```

=====

Comment: Bottom line I need to edit both tables from within the "Result Grid" or "Form Editor" in a GUI (Not physical type in any statement). Please  recommend ways I can do that - if Workbench can't please let me know a  tool that can ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing data through the editor(mysqlworkbench) it needs a table on where it should execute the update command and the where column. That's why you can edit the record only when you have executed `SELECT * FROM table` because result of this query has primary key and table So Updating the data through workbench will be allowed

If you are using join to get the record then the editor displays the record of both the tables. And workbench(editor) won't get the table and primary key to update.

Comment: The reason is that MySQL cannot UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT directly to two tables with the same sentence (but it can use multiple of them for reference).

Comment: @jynus. You cannot INSERT into multiple tables with one statement. But you can UPDATE/DELETE (I guess only Workbench cannot).

Comment: So is there a way (may be setup the table in such a way) for me a edit both tables from within the "Result Grid" or "Form Editor" - Not physical type in any statement. ?